# How to understand the method inEventLoop in Interface EventExecutor?

Tags: java, netty, nio

I am reading the source code of netty4.0. And I found that there are code like below in many places.How to understand it throughly? The following is a segment of class AbstractChannel.

```
if (eventLoop.inEventLoop()) {
    register0(promise);
} else {
    try {
        eventLoop.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                register0(promise);
            }
        });
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.warn(
            "Force-closing a channel whose registration task was not accepted by an event loop: {}",
            AbstractChannel.this, t);
        closeForcibly();
        closeFuture.setClosed();
        safeSetFailure(promise, t);
    }
}
```

Comment: This code check if it's running inside event loop. If yes, then invoke `register0(promise)` directly, else submit its execution to eventloop.

Answer (score 3):

Basically it is an "optimisation" that will directly invoke the code if the current `Thread` is the same that is tied to the `EventExecutor`. If not it needs to allocate a `Runnable` and pass it over for execution.

Comment: Can I understand it like this? Several channels allocated to a NioEventLoop, if operations on one of the channels are done by other thread, if not designed like this, it will cause concurrent problems?